# Which "known" ring is $K = \frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[X,Y]}{(Y-X^2, XY + Y + 2)}$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Which "known" ring is $K = \frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[X,Y]}{(Y-X^2, XY + Y + 2)}$ isomorphic to?

---

I am not 100% sure how to solve this. So far this is what I have:

I know that $(Y-X^2, XY + Y + 2)$ is the ideal, which means that $Y-X^2$ gets 'projected' to 0, in other words $Y=X^2$.

This then gives me that $XY + Y + 2 = X*X^2 + X^2 +2 = X^3 + X^2 + 2 = 0$.

But now I don't know what I have to do.
I have checked and 1,2,3,4 are not roots of the equation in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. So I'm a bit stuck on how to solve this question. Is what I have done so far correct, and how do I continue?

Comment: If $Y=X^2$, then $\mathbb{Z}_5[X,Y] "="\mathbb{Z}_5[X,X^2] "=" \mathbb{Z}_5[X]$. Now what is $\mathbb{Z}_5[X]/(X^3+X^2+2)$?

Comment: @crystal_math thats what i'm not entirely sure about. Its the field where everything is modulo $X^3 + X^2 + 2$. I know I can apply the division algorithm (for every polynomial over a ring with unity, we can write $f = gq + r$). But I don't know if that is what I need, nor do I know how I would use that to find a ring that it is isomorphic to.

Comment: First; the divison algorithm doesn't work for every ring with unity (think of $\mathbb{Z}$) but in this case it works: $\mathbb{Z}_5[X]$ is an euclidean domain. 

Second, $\mathbb{Z}_5[X]/(X^3+X^2+2)$ is a field (this is a hint). Moreover, I recommend, applying the Euclidean algorithm (when necessary) to compute some of the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_5[X]/(X^3+X^2+2)$. After that you can prove in generality what the elements should look like. $\textbf{I highly recommend this before looking at the other solutions below}$

Comment: @crystal_math I'm still not quite sure about how I would be able to prove in general what the elements would look like. Do I have to take an arbitrary polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ and calculate the remainder?

Comment: That's the end goal, but you should start with some examples to see the pattern

Comment: @crystal_math Oh okay, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by your remark $(Y-X^2,XY+Y+2) = (Y-X^2,X^3+X^2+2)$.

The assignment $X \to X, Y\to X^2$ defines an arrow $\tau \colon \Bbb Z_5[X,Y]/(Y-X^2) \to \Bbb Z_5[X]$. Surjectivity is clear, as for injectivity: pick $p(X,Y)$ in the kernel of $\tau$ and
via the identification $\Bbb Z_5[X,Y] = \Bbb Z_5[X][Y]$ divide $p$ by $Y-X^2$. Note that even though polynomial rings in several variables need not have euclidean algorithms, we can always divide by monomials (as in this case). Hence we have

$$
p(X,Y) = (Y-X^2)q(X,Y) + r(X).
$$

But then applying $\tau$ we get $r(X) = 0$ as desired.

Finally, by the third isomorphism theorem we have

$$
\Bbb Z_5[X,Y]/(Y-X^2, X^3+X+2) \simeq \Bbb Z_5[X]/(X^3+X^2+2).
$$

Note that the polynomial $X^3+X^2+2$ has no roots modulo $5$ and is thus irreducible in $\Bbb Z_5$. Therefore, the quotient is a field. To compute the order, you can note for example that it is a $\Bbb Z_5$ vector space of dimension $3$ over $\Bbb Z_5$.

Hence the quotient can be characterized as the field with $5^3$ elements.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the detailed answer! So would my answer have to be: it is isomorphic to the field with $5^3$ elements, or is there a specific field that I can say it is isomorphic to?

Comment: In general, any two finite fields of the same cardinality are isomorphic $5^3$. If you want a "concrete" presentation you could say that the elements of your field are $a + b \omega + c \omega^2$ with $a,b \in \Bbb Z_5$ and $\omega^3 = -(\omega^2+2)$. This will allow you to define an explicit multiplication rule.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I understand, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Very good.

You can prove that it's isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_5[X]/(X^3+X^2+2)$ and you already showed that polynomial has no roots in $\Bbb Z_5$.

Hence, it is irreducible (being of degree 3), so the quotient is the field of $5^3$ elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Is it enough to say that it is isomorphic to the field of $5^3$ elements, or is there a specific field that I should mention?

Comment: Up to isomorphism, there is only one field of $5^3$ elements. See [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field).

Comment: For every prime order $q=p^n$ there's a *unique* field (up to isomorphism) with that order, namely the splitting field of $f(x)=x^q-x$ over $\Bbb Z_p$. (Note that every element of a field of order $q$ is a root of $f$.)

Comment: Oh right! Thank you very much!